Practicality of weaponizing civilian container ships
I'm wondering about the practicality of weaponizing civilian cargo container ships in the modern world, for organizations engaging in asymmetric warfare, and/or being less technologically advanced or well-funded.
There have been examples of hijackings like Maersk Alabama or MSC Aries where people were able to seize control of the vessels. Alternatively, the organizations may gain military control over a commercial port and seize any cargo liners within.
There are different directions to approach the question of practicality:

How difficult is it to retrofit commercial ships with effective naval weapons? I imagine it'd be easy to install autocannons like a ZU-23 with a regular crane. There should also be plenty of space for an S-300 battery complete with the radars and TELs. The role of the naval gun could perhaps be filled by parking towed artillery pieces on board, since installing actual naval guns requires dealing with the large amount of machinery normally under the deck.
Are there any tactical or strategic benefit to doing something like this? I expect a converted liner can drastically extend the military reach of an organization, with the capability to launch cruise missile attacks from the open sea, and perhaps tending explosive sea drones like MAGURA V5. The liner would obviously be a huge target, but it may be economical to use swarms of liners armed with S-300 and basic AA missiles to trade against expensive fighter jets, Harpoons and ESSMs.
Could the asymmetrical group hide weaponry under cargo container shells and masquerade with regular commercial shipping traffic, and attacking with surprise?


We have a strict one question per post policy. Please edit this to ask a single specific question.

@sphennings Did you read the question in its entirety? I specifically wrote "there are different directions to approach the [singular] question of practicality" - to answer yes/no/maybe of whether it is practical, multiple details must be considered. I'm not sure how to ask a more singular question than "how's the practicality?"

How’s the practicality is too broad and undefined a question. You also ask about difficulty of retrofitting, tactical and strategic benefits of retrofitting, and hiding weapons in cargo containers. We aren’t like other sites. A big part of this is our policies about the sort of questions that are permissible. Specificity is a fundamental aspect of that.

What is the purpose of the weaponisation?  What type of opponent is the weaponised ship supposed to engage?  Naval vessels purposes include: patrolling waters to stop illegal fishing: signals intelligence gathering; "show the flag" diplomacy; convoy escort; force projection against other ships; amphibious assault; etc - without a tactical/strategic purpose and threat model there are too many possibilities to be analysed in a post of any reasonable length.

VTC:Too Story-Based. The solution is practical depending on the circumstances of the story. Whether or not it's practical in the Real World today doesn't matter here - but even if we consider it, it depends on the groups or nations involved, their goals, their adversries... their stories. Tell us the goal of the weaponization and we can help you with it. Asking us if it's practical makes no worldbuilding sense at all.

I see several questions here, and if they were broken out individually and given more background I think it would be an interesting series. eg 1) Would a "missile frigate" retrofitted from a container ship and a mobile TEL be able to [achieve specific objective]? 2) Would [specifically defined group] be able to acquire a container ship and retrofit it covertly given [setup]? etc. But I think the question both needs more details, and is at least 2 questions.

The only strategic uses I am aware of in actual history are the sinking of merchant ships across a strait to improvise a blockade. It was done by Egypt in 1956, and has been a lingering Iranian threat over the Strait of Hormuz since 1988.

As another poster noted the question doesn't define the mission you wish the  civilian ships to perform. In general purpose built warships will always perform the missions they were designed for better than some generic civilian craft with guns welded on to the deck. What  might make sense?  Equipping merchant ships with limited close range self defense capabilities in the form of containerized point defense such as RAM, chaff, decoy systems like NULKA & maybe anti torpedo defenses.  The key. The ships themselves don't control them directly they are tied into the convoy escort command network.

A boat is a hole in the water you throw money into. A big boat is a very big hole in the water you throw money into
What you’re imagining is basically an oversized naval technicals, (civilian pickup trucks converted for military use). Favored by warlords without big budgets, they’re a quick and easy way to project power. And like technicals, they'd face severe limitations against proper military vessels.
The key problems are basic survivability (no armor, no compartmentalization, no damage control systems), lack of proper military sensors/electronics, and cost. One missile, torpedo, or shell hit would likely be catastrophic. Also, modern naval warfare happens beyond visual range, and you’re putting a floating metal balloon with a radar signature the size of a small island  onto the field of battle. You’re fighting blind, under a spotlight, in the middle of the night, against opponents with night vision goggles and sniper rifles.
Smaller converted vessels (like fishing boats or speedboats) actually make more practical sense, and, notably, are how asymmetric naval warfare is actually typically conducted. They're cheaper, more maneuverable, harder to detect, and present a smaller target, and losing one isn’t a big deal in terms of invested resources.
Like technicals, these conversions might work for harassment of non-military targets, but would be extremely vulnerable to any proper naval force. The q-ship trick might work once against an unprepared target, though, as long as it’s not an actual naval ship.
One other thing that you’re missing is fuel costs. Cargo ships are insanely, ridiculously, obscenely expensive to run from a fuel perspective. I think it’s something like >500k for a single transatlantic voyage. As a floating weapons platform, moored in a bay it can’t really sink in, it might do okay though.

Mostly agree, except that recent experience with the Houthi rebels has shown that survivability of the ship is surprisingly good unless you fill the entire container ship with munitions/fuel that will result in a secondary explosion.  The majority of a cargo ship is non-critical systems, which means it takes a lucky or precisely aimed hit to destroy the mission-critical stuff.

@KerrAvon2055 I anm under the impression that the Houthis were very much not trying, particularly hard to sink the ships. When you want to sink a ship, you usually don’t repeatedly allow rescue and recovery operations from foreign navies in your alleged territorial waters.

And, notably, this hypothetical cargo ship technical would be loaded with things a lot more flammable than metal cargo containers

Anyone who can afford to fill a container ship with things that go boom can afford a better ship.  Unless it's a suicide (or unmanned) ship filled with ANFO intended to sail into a harbour incognito and deliberately replicate Halifax 1917 or Beirut 2020, there's no way an ill-funded organisation can buy enough munitions to occupy more than a tiny percentage of a typical container vessel.  As for the Houthis, one theory is they are using AIS to target merchant ships, they lack the sensor capabilities to detect and target naval vessels that turn their reporting beacons off.

@KerrAvon2055 I mean, I find the best explanation that they don't want to sink ships and get Operation Praying Mantis'd, they just want to deter commercial shipping, which harassing ships accomplishes just as easily. re: 'enough munitions', if they're only occupying a tiny fraction of the container vessel, they should use a different vessel, so the point that it's a bad idea still stands.

If you’re looking to do maximize damage to a hostile country using a cargo ship, you’re better off parking it in the Panama or Suez Canal like the 2021 Ever Given.

Big problem:  You're not putting normal land artillery on normal ships.

Gun goes boom.  Deck goes crunch.  Big guns need bracing built into the ship.

Gun goes boom.  Shell goes wild.  Naval artillery has to deal with the concept of a moving deck and will fire exactly when the barrel is pointed in exactly the right direction.  Land artillery has no concept of a moving firing platform and can't do this.



The problem with this is- that at the moment trade ships take part in conflict- its open season of everyone on all suspected ships, resulting in a rushing of all nations to find a protection partner. So total war, results in a total coalition forming, usually of everyone ganging up on the person starting the ruckus.
Then again- the military is big on pods and modularity:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tactical_Airborne_Reconnaissance_Pod_System
And especially on ships. Two results of this were:
A) New systems regularly are not proportional, as in they are not refined and shrunken down to fit into pods. Making customization necessary - or just a plug into the system, staying outside- so no container, just open space.
B) Energy is never enough. A regular container boat could never supply wasteful military systems in full. It has no firefighting capabilities, no heat disposal, no nothing. All there is - is one huge box of fire and forget, that could work out. Once. After that its remote scanning, far away from any valuable target, way before you approach, with x-ray bridge ships - or just two ships, one x-raying, the other receiving.
So this whole idea - is basically a one-trick pony.

Yes and No
Let me address the No first - which has mostly been articulated by the other posts - which is that Modern Weapons systems - even autonomous systems require special mounts, personnel, power and other things.
A Modern container ship, could maybe in theory have a container that had a small-ish calibre weapons system. But anything much larger than 40mm is liable to introduce all sorts of problems when it comes to recoil and structural stability.
Next up you have profit - assuming it is a Cargo ship designed to withstand a Pirate Attack - each container that is not profitable cargo, is a loss. Every additional crew member, is a loss etc. etc. You get the point
In addition, modern container ships are highly specialized for, well, containers. Same with Bulk Carriers. Ships are a big investment - and so rather than have 1 ship that does many jobs averagely, we have seen a lot of Min-Maxing whereby a Ship is specialized to do one thing brilliantly.
There are other considerations around if your ship is expected to take incoming fire - but I think I have made the point...
BUT!!
There IS historical precedent for this type of idea: The Q-Ships These were re-purposes merchant vessels by the Royal Navy, that had sufficiently nasty artillery to take on a Submarine and win (WW1 and WW2 Submarines were pretty fragile, compared to the likes of say a Battleship - and so taking one out with a 40 mm Bofors gun or a 3 inch cannon was not unreasonable.
You will note, in the Wikipedia section, it mentions their proposed usage against Somali Pirates.
In terms of effectiveness - they had a short period where they worked well, then after that, once the you have pulled the same Gag a few times, the Enemy starts to smarten up - and after that - they were not very useful, especially considering their cost vs other methods (Minefields, Destroyers etc.)
And this is where the answer comes in:
There is enough real-world precedent to have these type of Vessels in your world - but the practical reality is that they simply weren't that great - and it would be better to invest in a proper Military ship than trying to retrofit an existing ship.

I do mention q-ships in my answer, and come to the same conclusion (it might work once or twice) though I think I'm more skeptical than you that a container q-ship would work against a non-civilian vessel. Q-ships were mainly (not exclusively) effective against submarines. I would not want to attack a destroyer with a q-ship.

I totally missed that reference - I guess I was looking for a capital Q LD

To add to the historical precedent, the USS Jupiter was a bulk cargo ship commissioned in 1913. It was retrofitted into the 1st aircraft carrier, the USS Langley, in 1922.

Uneconomical
Rebels
Besides the answer of Daniel B there are several big problems. Putting guns on a cargo ship cost money. Not just by building it. It takes cargo space. That is a lot of cargo, and thus money, per trip. The extra weight for the guns and bracing will not help the fuel economy.
Then there's the targets. Against rebels and the like the naval guns are useless, unless they for some reason have bunched up. They can fire shoulder mounted anti-tank missiles, use fast attack boats or other small group tactics, making big naval guns all but useless. The MAGURA V5 have more use and a more reasonable cost. However, the chance that they get to blow up a single rubber boat out of several is small. It needs to be that exact ship to be attacked or be close by, or you need to install it on many boats, costing you more than ranson.
Big war
Maybe then a big war? As a surprise tactic they might be able to take down a cruiser. Not to mention you have so many guns you can overwjelm them.
It wouldn't work. The ships attend international harbours. It will be noticed that you have a suspicious amount of your own nationality on a ship, the military qualified to operate and maintain the guns. They'll be more than your normal crew as well. Not to mention the huge amount of containers always staying on board. The cargo containers that hide the guns. They'll also need to go to military harbours at some time for maintenance. There is no way any military intelligence of note will not know, making the ships am easy military target. You destroy economy as well as a huge military investment. That is powerful. In 'normal war' they wwould be civilian ships and never a legitimate target.
If the ships are military only they are even worse. From ship transponder data, or the lack thereof, it will be instantly known they do not go to ports for on or offloading, attend military harbours and have military movements at times. They'll be sunk before they can 'reveal' their true nature in surprise.
Drones
The MAGURA V5 is the only one that makes some sense though. Drones in general will be perfect. Especially in another decade when the technology is further refined.
Most drones are small, making them much easier to hide, as well as not take much in nature of fuel economy. For example, the huge bays for the anchor chains in the ship offer a place to hide many small drones in a place where people seldom go. They could burst out of the hull in numbers with seceral kinds of purposes. Small kamikaze drines for rebels in boats or the beach. Maybe a few bigger ones with guns. Launch a few quick strikes, or a swarm of difficult to intercept drones to overwhelm them.
For the big militaries the MAGURA V5 is excellent. The earlier mentioned drones could cause some minor damage and chaos on the deck of an enemy ship. The MAGURA V5 can sink it. The same tactic can be ysed where this drone is hidden in a part of the ship. It'll be covertly released when required, able to surprise a strike group.
Other uses
Another big job for them we can see currently around the baltic sea. The boats use anchors to damage important data or electricity lines. There are also a lot of smaller 'trawlers' that might have tiny submarines on board.
You could avoid suspicion by letting a submarine drone loose when passing such lines. It'll sink to the bottom, waiting a day, week or month to act. It can explode, or simply cut the cable with a torch and move a few kilometres away so it'll not be found. Maybe to be picked uo again, or resurface with solar panels to attack something else later. The possibilities to arm such ships are there, though it'll only be 'small' adaptations for small military hardware. With drones the opportunities are there.

Real Life Examples - Q-Ships and Armed merchantmen
This has been done in real life during WWII.
The allies added anti aircraft guns on to merchant ships, and to a lesser extent anti submarine weapons or canons for use against surface raiders. In most cases the weapons were manned by trained military personnel.
These didn't prove to be especially effective because the merchant ships often lacked the secondary systems to use the weapons effectively, and it was simply easier and more effective to make escort ships and to allow the merchants to concentrate on evading enemies while their escorts engaged.
Q-Ships were merchant ships with hidden weapons deployed by various military as traps for surface raiders and u-boats/submarines.
They had some limited effectiveness early on but once word got out they became easy to track and east to spot. Their weapons were generally smaller and had to be kept hidden, so when a raider spotted one they pounded it from long range or simply ignored it.
Weapons and ports\docks
In science fiction the Millennium Falcon can dock pretty much anywhere it wants whenever it wants. In real life, the vast majority of docks and ports wouldn't allow something with mounted weapons anywhere near in case of accidents or in case they were pirates.
This is why - for example - Russian ships traveling in areas with high levels of piracy have armed mercenaries on board rather than fixed weapons emplacements. The mercenaries usually have their own support vessel and they decamp when the ship goes into harbor.

If you had the resources for an all out war, they would make useful troop transports.
The only use for the ships themselves would be if this is not an asymmetric war, but one where you already hold naval and aerial superiority, at least in a given theater of operations.  Storage containers are pretty easy to turn into improvised dormitories; so, a single ship could be used to move thousands of troops and many many tons of military equipment.
Otherwise, Weaponize the Containers, not the Ships
The ships themselves are terrible warships, and there is nothing you can do to make them good warships unless you have a big budget to make them so... however, what if you are not trying to control the whole ship, but rather, just have some influence over the ports that they land in.  A single cargo container is big enough to contain several drones or cruise missiles.
If you controlled the port, then you could stack palletized weapon systems that resemble cargo containers right on top of a ship full of legitimate cargo.  Then when the ship gets within range of enemy naval assets, it opens up to fire on the enemy while the actual crew of the ship are just civilians doing their jobs.

Yeah: a ship could take out a city. The 2002 Beirut blast, 1,7k tons ammonium nitrate, 6th largest non-nuke explosion ever, was just from one small cargo-ship, the MV Rhosus. Ammonium Nitrate costs USD466/ton, so filling a 400k DWT Chinamax ship would cost USD186M, about the same as the ship itself. USD350M to deliver a 160 kT bomb seems low compared to billions for nukes a tenth the size for Hiroshima/Nagasaki. Well within budgets of governments, big business, terror orgs, etc. Containers of concrete or steel over the nitrates could even make a shaped charge, at the cost of some payload.

Your Questions:

How difficult is it to retrofit commercial ships with effective naval weapons?

The current naval "Meta" (ignoring submarines) is focused on projecting power beyond visual range (BVR). This means platforms such as aircraft carriers are dominant along with guided missile destroyers, which are essentially just launchpads for long-range missiles.
While I do not think it would be easy to retrofit a container ship into acting as an aircraft carrier, utilizing a container ship as the platform from which to launch drones and missiles would not be particularly difficult, provided with the right weapons systems (eg containerized missile batteries).
Similarly, providing primitive air-defense by parking land-based mobile air defense vehicles on the deck of the ship could, in theory, provide basic protections.
Mounting a cannon or similar is nearly completely pointless and would be ineffective. In modern naval BVR combat there is no purpose for any sort of gun or artillery system, beyond something like CIWS for defense or for a coastal bombardment role, however this is one you are not going to be in if you are engaging in asymmetric warfare against a technologically and militarily superior foe (they can blast you with long-range missiles far before you get close enough to any coastal target that your artillery would be in range).
Additionally, I find it very unlikely that conventional land-based mobile artillery systems would be able to set up accurate firing solutions if they had to deal with the sway of being on a ship along with movement. Maybe the most advanced current vehicles, but if you have access to those, then you also have a navy.

Are there any tactical or strategic benefit to doing something like this?

Not really, but sorta. To me, this whole thing strikes me as a one-off trick, especially in a "tactical" sense. Sure, there is a scenario where a pirated container ship has its containers stealthily replaced with disguised missile launch tubes, and gets close enough to sneak up to an enemy port for a single surprise attack before it gets blown up, but like, then what? The trick will not work again. From then on, any cargo ship that so much as launches a single hobbyist drone while at sea--which can easily be spotted on radar--will rapidly become very well-acquainted with a sea-skimming anti-ship cruise missile.
In the strategic sense, this approach could be "beneficial" as it would damage the economies of globalized industrialized nations worldwide. Remember that the Evergreen Ever-Given which got stuck in the Suez had severe economic consequences world wide that echoed for quite a long time. If there were suddenly someone out there who is causing shipping lines to switch to an extreme risk-mitigation strategy, and introduce the need to regularly board and inspect container ships, that would have consequences.

Could the asymmetrical group hide weaponry under cargo container shells and masquerade with regular commercial shipping traffic, and attacking with surprise?

Once, maybe.
My take
This doesn't make much sense. The only slight positive I see is the "terrorism" angle where you cause global economic disruption by disturbing shipping temporarily, but beyond that, this is a losing strategy. To make asymmetric warfare work, you need to focus on rapidly repositionable, low-cost, expendable assets, which a huge container ship is not.
Sure, you could technically probably outfit a captured container ship into some sort of short-lifetime "naval technical" by parking a couple soviet-era air defense and missile launch systems on the deck, but this would not be credibly threatening to a T1 military power such as the USA or more broadly, NATO. If you had the ability to make it credibly threatening (proper VLS cells, etc) you wouldn't need to resort to pirating clunky cargo ships to build your navy.
In the current military "meta" for asymmetric warfare, I'd sooner reach towards these alternatives:

Lots of cheap speedboats. You can get a swarm of 50 cheap speedboats, fill each with a bunch of dudes (who are all ready to die for the cause etc), and arm them with RPGs and explosive satchels. Lots of them won't make it to the target, but a rather low investment on your part can cost the enemy significantly. For example, if the enemy has to spend 1.2 million for each missile to blow up a single speedboat, then you can cause >$50m in "damages" all for the cost of a couple thousand bucks in end-of-life speedboats and some new martyrs for the cause.

Smaller deniable military assets. Instead of large container or cargo ships, convert local fishermen and their boats to the cause. You can then use these fishing boats to organize blockades, or even equip them with explosives to discourage inspection. The enemy can't realistically prevent all your people from going fishing, nor can they really inspect every single fishing boat, and this would be a cheap way of foisting expenses on your enemy.




... it may be economical to use swarms of liners armed with S-300 and basic AA missiles to trade against expensive fighter jets, Harpoons and ESSMs.

Getting hold of large numbers of S-300 systems is really challenging these days. They've being used up in Ukraine quite quickly. These armed merchantmen may work as Q-ships, briefly, but then they'll find out what the real instrument of naval power is these days.
Submarines.
Q-ships had uses against WWI submarines that were trying to conserve torpedoes, so they used their deck guns to sink smaller merchantmen. Against a modern submarine, the first thing the merchantmen is likely to know about the fight is a torpedo explosion under the keel, followed by the realisation they're sinking.
Read up on the sinking of ARA General Belgrano. That was over forty years ago, during which submarines and torpedoes have improved considerably. Your merchant vessels are less capable of defending themselves             against a submarine attack than that Argentine Navy force was. It will be a slaughter.

There were suggestions to containerize things like anti-ship missiles (something like the Harpoon or Exocet) to greatly increase the number of "shooting vessels" in a navy.

USNI
Defense News
The Warzone, angain TWZ.

The thing is that these "budget arsenal ships" would augment a traditional fleet. A task force of more typical warships would get some missile-armed freighters to extend the number of missiles in their magazines, while the "real" warships handle the complicated targeting and protect the missile ships.
